# Presentation of the amalgamated product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ above $H$ is $ \langle S_1,S_2\; ; \; R_1,R_2,\phi_1(s)\phi_{2}^{-1}(s),s \in S \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation, free-product

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553754/free-product-of-groups-with-presentations), I found the proof of presentation of the free product of groups. I wanted to show the same thing for amalgamated free product of 2 groups i.e.

Show that  that if $H$ is generated by $S$, and $ \phi_1 : H \rightarrow G_1 , \phi_2 : H \rightarrow G_2$ are morphisms of groups then the amalgamated product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ above $H$ is

$$
G_1 *_{H} G_2 = \langle S_1,S_2\; ; \; R_1,R_2,\phi_1(s) ( \phi_{2}(s) )^{-1},s  \in S \rangle
$$

where $G_1 = \langle S_1 \; ; \; R_1 \rangle$ and $G_2 = \langle S_2 \; ; \; R_2 \rangle$.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`; the latter are symbols, not delimeters.

Comment: This isn’t the amalgamated product unless $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are embeddings (so that $H$ can be viewed as a subgroup of both). If you do not include the assumption that they are embeddings, what you describe is the [pushout of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: I think I have found out the solution using help from Derek Holt's solution from here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1553839 and http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~chiswell/ggt/lecture_notes/lecture2.pdf. It is just the application of universal property. I will write my solution later.